# nodejs use gm module to process the images but I need it sync

Tags: javascript, node.js

here are two method .but i need it to finish sync.But it is failed.
I want to use the Promise.all to keep it sync but i find the images process is async and it can't reject or resolve in a loop! It really makes me confused .
below is my code.I can't catch the res or err. it just end after processed the images...even don't excute the test Method,but i wonder that Promise.all is a sync method? And is there any way to catch the res or err information? Thanks !

```
var gm = require('gm')
var fs = require('fs')
var config = require('./imgConfig')
var image = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg','5.jpg','6.jpg']
var _image = ['_1.jpg', '_2.jpg', '_3.jpg', '_4.jpg','_5.jpg','6.jpg']


testS()

function testS() {
    uploadFiles(image, _image, 'subModule').then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
    })
}

function uploadFiles(inputArray, outputArray, type) {
    return Promise.all([multipleResize(inputArray, outputArray, type), test()])
}

function test() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("object");
            resolve("yeah")
        }, 100)
    })
}


function multipleResize(inputArray, outputArray, type) {
    var height = config[type].height;
    var width = config[type].width;
    return Promise.all(inputArray.map((img, index) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            gm(config.inputPath + img)
                .resizeExact(width, height)
                .noProfile()
                .write(config.outputPath + outputArray[index], function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    try {
                        fs.unlinkSync(config.inputPath + img); // consider using an async method here as well.
                        console.log("next" + config.outputPath + outputArray[index]);
                        console.log('ko');
                        return resolve();
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error(e);
                        reject(e);
                    }
                });
        });
    }));
}
```

imgConfig

```
module.exports = {
        'subModule': {
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        },
        inputPath:'./input/',
        outputPath:'./output/'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `multipleResolve`, you are running `return resolve()` as part of the `#forEach()` call. This probably isn't what you want, as the first iteration will resolve the promise you returned, even though all of your `gm` `.write()` calls won't be finished yet.

I would consider doing something like this -- note the internal use of `Promise.all()` and the `inputArray#map()` to convert each `img`/`index` pair to their own `Promise`. I also swapped around some of the error logic to make sure the errors are checked as soon as possible.

```
function multipleResize(inputArray, outputArray, type) {
    var height = config[type].height;
    var width = config[type].width;
    var flag = 0;
    return Promise.all(inputArray.map((img, index) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            gm(config.inputPath + img)
                .resizeExact(width, height)
                .noProfile()
                .write(config.outputPath + outputArray[index], function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    try {
                        fs.unlinkSync(config.inputPath + img); // consider using an async method here as well.
                        console.log("next" + config.outputPath + outputArray[index]);
                        flag++;
                        console.log('ko');
                        return resolve();
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error(e);
                        reject(e);
                    }
                });
        });
    }));
}
```

Side note, you seem to be using promises (mostly) correctly, but you are incorrectly calling them `sync`, when they typically aren't synchronous.

Comment: it really can catch the res or the err , but there is remain a problem that ,when i catch the res or err ,there are any promise haven't  done..And i am afraid that they will cause the err .So how to fix this problem? I am update the code your give.It is necessary to run test. But i think join this method cause this problem?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm having a hard time understanding your english. `Promise.all()` returns a single `Promise` which will be resolved when *every* promise in the array you pass to `Promise.all()` is completed. With my rewrite, the `Promise` returned from `multipleResize()` should *not* resolve until each `Promise` wrapped around the `gm.write()` calls have all resolved. In the case of an error, that single `Promise` will be rejected on the first error, and everything else is just sort of in limbo (but that's by design).

Comment: The [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) mdn docs may be helpful to you.

Comment: I am sorry for my English. Thanks for your help i solve the problem finnaly!

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for. :) Glad you got it sorted out!